# Alternative to GetDefaultFolder to pull information from an online calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I'm trying pull the calendar information from "Markdown Calendar" (a calendar that's subscribed to) into Excel.

It's an online calendar, not in the same location as my default.

Code I found online pulls from my own calendar.

How do I change `GetDefaultFolder` to the markdown calendar?

```vb
Sub Markdown_Calendar()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olApt As Object
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim olFolderNew As Object    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")    
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9)    
    Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Subject", "Start", "End", "Location")    
    NextRow = 2    
    For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
        Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.Subject
        Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = olApt.Start
        Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = olApt.End
        Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = olApt.Location
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    Next olApt    
    Set olApt = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing    
    Columns.AutoFit    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not exactly so, depends on whether it is shared folder or not. And then where the folder is located if it is not a shared one only.

Comment: Where is that folder located? Same mailbox where your default Calendar folder is? If yes, is it a subfolder of the Calendar folder? Or on the same level as the Calendar folder?

Comment: It's an online calendar, not in the same location as my default.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method helpful, it is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder).

Also you can get the default calendar folder (or the parent folder) and try to iterate over all subfolders to find the required one. Or just navigating through the tree of folders in Outlook, for example:

```
OutlookApp.Session.Folders(yourDefaultStore.DisplayName).Folders("Calendar Name")
```